# Cant get the data from form post to nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, html

I am trying to write a login page . i got the html page with the login box 
im enter email and password than submit to server , on server i got route who get the data check on db if doc exists , if its exists should redirect to main page 
the problem is the data i send from form to server always undefined i check here on other ppl questions and i didnt find any good result for this

html login page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
     <title>{{PageTitle}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> header}}

    <div class="login-box">
      <div class="form">
        <form action="/get_user" method="post" class="login-form">
          <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <button type="submit">login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{> footer}}
 </body>
```

server code :

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
const hbs = require('hbs');

var {User} = require('./models/user');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
const port = process.env.PORT;
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/../views/partials');

app.user(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/images'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/fonts'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.hbs', {
    PageTitle: 'Log In',
    ConnectUser: 'Guest'
  });
});

app.post('/get_user', (req, res) => {
 var body = _.pick(req.body, ['Email , 'Password']);

 User.findOne({
   Email: body.Email,
   Password: body.Password
 }).then((user) => {
  console.log(body.Email + ' ' + body.Password);
  if(!user) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  var fullName = user.First_Name + ' ' + user.Last_Name;
  res.redirect('/mainPage', {ConnectUser: fullName});
}).catch((e) => {
  res.status(400).send();
 });
});
```

i did few checks and when i call /get_user req.body->var body -> user r empty
the data arnt pass from form to server im also check this route on postman and its work find when i write the body by myself the only problem i can think is the data i send from form arnt send as json and the body parser send only in json format so maybe i need to change the line

> app.use(bodyParser.json());

if any 1 can put in the right direction ill appraise that ty.

Comment: Try `console.log(req)` and `req.body`. I am guessing the problem comes when you do `_.pick(...`

Comment: Theres a typo in your server sample, not the root of your problem if its actually in your code, but should be ‘app.use’ instead if ‘app.user’

Comment: its only here , in my code its "use" and some 1 just find the problem ty for ur responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### When using an html form with method post, the data is posted to the server with`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.

Json bodyparser will not do anything with that, as its not using JSON format to send the data. See [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#Where_does_the_data_go) under post method.

In your server code, below `app.use(bodyParser.json())` add the following:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

This will add the data onto the request body the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the form enc-type attribute and see how to configure the bodyparser to get the values you need based on the enc-type.

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype